# Github rejecting large file despite lfs

Tags: git, github, git-lfs

I have a large file which is tracked with lfs. However github still rejects it.

I actually was able to bring the file size down considerably but I still can't push.

I've verified that the file is tracked with lfs via `git lfs ls-files`

Here is the error I get when I try to push:

```
Uploading LFS objects: 100% (23/23), 210 MB | 0 B/s, done.
Enumerating objects: 177, done.
Counting objects: 100% (177/177), done.
Delta compression using up to 12 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (102/102), done.
Writing objects: 100% (102/102), 369.48 KiB | 434.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 102 (delta 63), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (63/63), completed with 47 local objects.
remote: error: Trace: 1e2d1dd7815caa92be761a87d6f90afaca999e05b2f21e34d68c3965ed04618f
remote: error: See https://gh.io/lfs for more information.
remote: error: File Assets/Scenes/Main.unity is 102.54 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
remote: error: GH001: Large files detected. You may want to try Git Large File Storage - https://git-lfs.github.com.
To github.com:arcadeperfect/Phys-Clock-Unity.git
 ! [remote rejected] mac -> mac (pre-receive hook declined)
```

edit

I have followed the install guide at [github](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/working-with-files/managing-large-files/installing-git-large-file-storage) and tracked the file with lfs, and verified that the file in question is tracked via lfs according to `git lfs ls-files`

Comment: Did you follow the steps at https://git-lfs.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can following those steps:

1. git lfs track ".unity"
2. Convert file to lfs: git lfs migrate import --include="*.unity"
3. git push --force
4. Clean up the .git directory (optional)

- git reflog expire --expire-unreachable=now --all
- git gc --prune=now

Refer link: https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/wiki/Tutorial#migrating-existing-repository-data-to-lfs

Comment: Sorry if I am missing something. I have installed and configured lfs according to 
https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/working-with-files/managing-large-files/installing-git-large-file-storage - I can't find any setting in github itself that needs to be enabled. Unless you mean my git repo locally, in which I have enabled lfs and as noted, verified that the file in question is tracked with lfs

Comment: Sorry for my mismatch. I have updated the answer.